# .Net core api response is in small case how to change default settings

Tags: c#

After Migrating .Net Framework MVC API to .Net Core, Json Response was changed. Property Names are in small. How to override default settings for Lowercase

Answer (score 0):

We can use below setting in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();   
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
    }
```

Or we can add as

```
 services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```